# Resize columns in KendoUI Grid Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I am looking for way to manage resize columns by user in Angular 2 application. I saw in another versions of KendoUI Grid (for example in AngularJS) that this is possible but I can't find any solution for that in Angular 2 technology. Did they support that or it will be added later?

Also I thinking about reorder columns. And like in last question, I saw in another versions of KenduUI that this feature is implemented but I can't find any way to do that in Angular 2? Should I wait for next versions of Kendo or there is simple way to make it on my own now? Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the release candidate version this feature was not implemented so; Yes, you should wait for the release that's coming in early May, (as it says on its web page).

You should check out the Sortable component that allows you to drag and reorder elements, maybe there's a way to implement this with the grid.

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/